# Embedding Videos onto your website

Tags: video, dreamweaver, web, embedded-video

I have a website where I am embedding a video onto. I am just wondering if having an embedded video on the page would make the video load and buffer, and run less smoothly, than if the video where actually placed on the page? Thanks

Comment: This is nothing to do with embedded software.  Please can you retag, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it depends what you mean by "embed".

Do you mean:

1. using the HTML 5 video tag?
2. using the old school object tag, and serving the video file yourself?
3. serving a flash player yourself?
4. using an embedding "script" which loads all the magic at runtime from somewhere else?
5. some other way... there a re many more ways, these are just some common ones

### Update Based on Comments

right right. Ok, well, then, using that method (**#4**) does not affect how the video is downloded at all.

See, by "embedding", using some scripts, all you're doing is setting up the player container somewhere else.. youtube, vimeo, your other site etc.

The only thing that will alter the "performance" of the video is a combination of the player itself (flash, html5, and the configs), and the server technology which is serving up the video file itself (IIS,Flash Server, Akami, etc etc).

Simple answer to your question: **No**

Comment: I mean embed as in "using an embedding "script" which loads all the magic at runtime from somewhere else". I have another website where I placed the video on the page and created scripting embed code which I placed onto the page I now have the video embedded on. (I used the other website, where the actual video is, for it has unlimited space)

Comment: and I assumed embeding someone elses flash player(eg Embed a youtube file).  You raised good points.

Answer (score 0):

The way an embedded video is downloaded and buffer eddepened on the player, eg Youtube flash player plays flv differently to the myspace flash video control.

*than if the video where actually placed on the page?*

I assume you mean as a download link, it would depend on the player and the video format.

Comment: yer, no I put the video up and created the embedding code myself. I'm just not sure whether it would work better just placing it onto the actual page, instead of embedding the video, would make a difference; for currently it is not running that smoothly.